# Strava API is_kom

Tags: strava

I would like to find out if I am the KOM on a specific segment.
According to the API this should be possible using: "https://www.strava.com/api/v3/segments/{id}"

**This should return a DetailedSegment. However, the athlete_pr_effort data is not contained in the response.**

When iterating over starred segments, you also get a DetailedSegment instance and the athlete_pr_effort is set like expected. In my case, the segment is not starred though.

Any idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

The Strava Segment Leaderboard endpoint was deprecated. It used to exist here:

`https://www.strava.com/api/v3/segments/:id/leaderboard`

Strava's update mid 2020:
https://developers.strava.com/docs/segment-changes/

It also states that you need to be a subscriber to get the `kom_rank` field (which I think is what you're looking for).

> /api/v3/segments/:id/leaderboard Segment Effort & Leaderboard data,
> included fields such as kom_rank, are only available for subscribers
> in the following endpoints.
>
> /api/v3/segments/:id /api/v3/segment_efforts [Updated]
> /api/v3/segment_efforts/:id/streams /api/v3/activities/:id

Comment: kom_rank is not correct. The documentation says: The rank of the effort on the global leaderboard if it belongs in the top 10 at the time of upload. However, I want to know if this is currently the best time. This is supposed to be is_kom (Whether this effort is the current best on the leaderboard), but is_kom is not contained in the response.

Comment: The sample response for https://www.strava.com/api/v3/segments/{id} does not contain "athlete_pr_effort" but does contain "athlete_segment_stats". I see that the example object representation does, as you note. I would guess that you need to be a subscriber to access "is_kom" (given their previous update that I linked to above about restricting viewing of your KOM position to subscribers only).

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I am a subscriber and I checked if the API thinks I am a subscriber by calling the /athlete/ API.

Comment: No worries. It might be worth an email to them. I had some queries a couple of years ago and they were good at getting back to me and answering follow up questions.

Comment: Unfortunately, they told me that the team is currently unable to give support to individuals.

Answer (score 0):

replace 9999999 with your athlete ID https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athletes/9999999/koms/?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxx